How to make integration tests for a Spring Boot library?
I'm currently working on my own project. The project is split into a RESTful service and a library. The RESTful service is a regular Spring Boot application, and it depends on my library. My library contains the most logic to process and store the incoming data from the service.
Now I'm at the point where my service and library are working smoothly together, but my library is missing some test. I thought that the best way to test my library would be one hand unit-tests to test my methods and on the other hand integration-tests to test some more processes in my library. E.g. receiving data from my outer layer, processing the data and storing the data in a database.
So as I already mentioned I build my second project as a library so it misses some plugins like:
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.5'

This is my build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}
...
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-beans:6.1.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context:6.1.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:6.1.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.2.4'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    implementation 'jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:2.1.1'
    implementation 'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.1.0'

    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.3.0'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'

    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'

}

I found some information on Google that led me to use @DataJpaTest to provide the connection to my database, but it gives me a "Cannot resolve symbol 'DataJpaTest'" error message. I guess the root of this problem is that my library is maybe missing some plugins.
My problem is I'm a little clueless how I should proceed now and what the best practice way would be in my situation.

Are you trying to add that @DataJpaTest in the main sources instead of the test sources? Because org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test pulls in org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure, which contains that annotation org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest

No I added a new class under my test folder. But yes that is why I'm clueless and don't know what I should do.

I found my problem. After mentioning if I'm adding my @DataJpaTest to the wrong resource, I checked my artifacts. The problem was, testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test' was not imported because I did not provided a version.
